# Do I need Struts to get tiles to work?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

- what files or plugins do I need to get tiles:insert to work? Do I need struts?
  I'm about 2 seconds away of just doing JSP include for everything.
  plz help thx!!

Answer (score 2):

You do NOT need Struts to use tiles. You can use just plain JSPs. If you need JSP support, copy the tiles-jsp-VERSION.jar to the WEB-INF/lib directory of your web application.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like the decorator pattern would suit you..

check out sitemesh
http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/